# Java Spring IOC constructor-arg inject a List<Integer>

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, constructor-injection

i am trying to develop a `Spring bean` like this

```
<bean id="id" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope='prototype'>
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class='MyClass'>
                <property name='id' value='1313'/>
                <property name="name" value='John Lennon'/>
                <property name='wifes'>                        
                    <list>
                        <bean class="WifeClazz">
                            <constructor-arg index='0' value='Cynthia Lennon'/>
                            <constructor-arg index='1'>                                    
                                <list><value>1962</value><value>1968</value></list>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>                 
                    </list>                 
                </property>
            </bean>             
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

this is just a example the `WifeClazz` the name is just for the example.. have a Constructor which have a String and a series of Integers.. `like this example`

```
new WifeClazz("Cinthia Lennon",java.util.Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));
```

the integers may be a severals from 1 to 10 integers.

but i think is kind of annoying do something like this

```
<constructor-arg index='1'>                                    
      <list>
          <value>1</value>
          <value>2</value>
          <value>3</value>
          <value>4</value> 
      </list>
 </constructor-arg>
```

would be great if i could do something like this

```
  <constructor-arg index='1'>
       <value>#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(1,2,3,4)}</value>
  </constructor-arg>
```

but throws Exception any clue?

any help is hugely appreciate.

**UPDATE**

I have change my code according Edwin a something like this.

```
<constructor-arg index="1" type="java.util.Collection" value="#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(1,2,3,4,5)}"/>
```

but throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Final expected argument should be array type (the varargs parameter)
```

my target clazz is

```
public MyClass(final String name,final List<Integer>years){}
```

my resulting code

```
<bean id="id" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope='prototype'>
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean class='MyClass'>
            <property name='id' value='1313'/>
            <property name="name" value='John Lennon'/>
            <property name='wifes'>                        
                <list>
                    <bean class="WifeClazz">
                        <constructor-arg index='0' value='Cynthia Lennon'/>
                        <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.util.Collection" value="#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(1,2,3,4,5)}"/>
                    </bean>                 
                </list>                 
            </property>
        </bean>             
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

this solves the trick...

```
<constructor-arg index='1' type="java.util.List" value="#{{1,2,3,4,5}}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
<bean id="list" class="java.util.ArrayList">
 <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(1,2,3,4,5)}"/>
</bean>
```

To disambiguate constructors, this also works for me

```
<bean id="list" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.Collection" value="#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(1,2,3,4,5)}"/>
</bean>
```

You can also use a collection SPeL, like this, and avoid having to use Arrays.asList directly.

```
<bean id="list" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.Collection" value="#{{1,2,3,4,5}}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: i have try this on the second constructor parameter Edwin. `<constructor-arg index="1" value="#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(1,2,3,4,5)}"/>` but not success. what i am doing wrong

Comment: could you expose your answer a little more. explain it a little more.

Comment: The difference is that I am using index 0 and you are using index 1.

Comment: i dont understand your `id` bean is used for... please see my edited question.

Comment: this works. `<constructor-arg index='1' type="java.util.List" value="#{{1,2,3,4,5}}"/>` saludos a Costa rica..